# Deprecated RCTEventDispatcher methods and RCTEventEmitter problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am very new to React Native development and I have no idea about Objective C and Xcode.
But as React Native produces the .xcworkspace project, I am unable to build that using Xcode.
In `RCTFBSDKLoginButtonManager.m` file there are two mwthods:

```
#pragma mark - FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error
{
  NSDictionary *event = @{
    @"type": @"loginFinished",
    @"target": loginButton.reactTag,
    @"error": error ? RCTJSErrorFromNSError(error) : [NSNull null],
    @"result": error ? [NSNull null] : @{
      @"isCancelled": @(result.isCancelled),
      @"grantedPermissions": result.isCancelled ? [NSNull null] : result.grantedPermissions.allObjects,
      @"declinedPermissions": result.isCancelled ? [NSNull null] : result.declinedPermissions.allObjects,
    },
  };
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendInputEventWithName:@"topChange" body:event];
}

- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
{
  NSDictionary *event = @{
    @"target": loginButton.reactTag,
    @"type": @"logoutFinished",
  };
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendInputEventWithName:@"topChange" body:event];
}

@end
```

Whenever I'm trying to build the project, I'm getting the error

> No visible @interface for 'RCTEventDispatcher' declares the selector 'sendInputEventWithName:body:'

where `sendInputEventWithName` is called, i.e., `[self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendInputEventWithName:@"topChange" body:event];`

I am stuck at this point and do not know how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved when run yarn add git+https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk.git to get from master branch.
Hope this helps!

Comment: awesome yarn trick.  man o man is that gonna save me time...  boundless amounts of future time that was destined to be wasted grinding gears of rnfbsdk's bugs...  THANKS!!!